# How to get a property from another property in JS?

Tags: javascript

The following code works, but I would like to know if is possible to to get b from c without mentioning a

---

```
var a = {
    b: {
        x: true
    },
    c: {
      check: function(){
      var test = a.b.x; // b.x I would like not to mention a. This does not work.
           alert('value is ' + test); 
      } 
    }
}
a.c.check();
```

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: why any specific problem in mentioning `b`?

Comment: You can't find an element inside an array without saying anything about the array! For other array options refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: This fields like the X/Y problem. ***Why*** don't you want to use `a` within `check`? `a` is a singleton. If we knew the real problem you were trying to solve, we might be able to help you solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have to specify `a` somehow so js knows which function you want to call.

What you could do is sth like

```
var a = {
    b: {
        x: true
    },
    c: {
      check: function(){
      var test = this.b.x;
           alert('value is ' + test); 
      } 
    }
}
a.c.check.call(a);
```

Or you could bind check to `a`:

```
var a = {
  b: {
    x: true
 }
}
a.c = {
  check: function(){
     var test = this.b.x;
     alert('value is ' + test); 
  }.bind(a) 
}
a.c.check();
```

Or link to b:

```
var a = {
  b: {
    x: true
  }
};
a.c = {
  b: a.b,
  check: function(){
    var test = this.b.x;
    alert('value is ' + test); 
  } 
}
a.c.check();
```